# How would I convert a cell into a button in excel (2016) to create a tally counter?

Tags: excel

I have cells that have names in them

```
     -------------------
    |id  |   name       |
     -------------------
    | 1  |    name_1    |
     -------------------
    | 2  |    name_2    |
     -------------------
    | 3  |    name_3    |
     -------------------
    | 4  |    name_4    |
     -------------------
    | 5  |    name_5    |
     -------------------
```

I would like to click on cells in the name column and it will incriment a 1 in the adjacent cell for example

```
     ----------------------------
    |id  |   name       | Count  |
     ----------------------------
    | 1  |    name_1    |   20   |
     ----------------------------
    | 2  |    name_2    |   34   |
     ----------------------------
    | 3  |    name_3    |   12   |
     ----------------------------
    | 4  |    name_4    |   50   |
     ----------------------------
    | 5  |    name_5    |   56   |
     ----------------------------
```

I don't want to use a spin button or go through about 1000 rows converting each cell into a physical button and then write code for each button.

Is there an easier wat to do this and how would I do that?

Comment: What about making a 1000 buttons but assigning each button the same code.  Ie when button pushed, increase the value of the cell to the right by 1?

Comment: I only know how to code each button to do what I want it to, but not one omni code that would function all buttons like that ...

Comment: You can make a cell **act like** a button by making them into hyperlinks and using an event macro to perform necessary functions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, a bit of a novice at macros and vba

Comment: @Gary'sStudent is there an event similar to onsave but instead on cell selection and then use that to trigger code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hyperlink solution:

First select the block of cells in the `Name` column and run this short macro:

```
Sub HyperActive()
    Dim nm As String

    nm = ActiveSheet.Name & "!"
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        addy = nm & r.Address(0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            addy, TextToDisplay:=r.Text
    Next r
End Sub
```

This will convert the text into active hyperlinks *(these hyperlinks don't actually go anywhere!)*

Then place the following **Event Macro** in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range(Target.SubAddress)
    r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
End Sub
```

It is the event macro the bumps the adjacent cell.